# Infix to postix conversion

Tags: java, algorithm, converting, stack

I'm looking for code review, optimizations and best practices.

Also verifying complexity to be O(n), where *n* is the string length.

```
public final class InfixToPostfix {

    private static final char PLUS = '+';
    private static final char MINUS = '-';
    private static final char MULTIPLY = '*';
    private static final char DIVIDE = '/';
    private static final char OPENBRACE = '(';
    private static final char CLOSEBRACE = ')';

    private InfixToPostfix() {
    }

    private static boolean isOperator(char c) {
        return c == PLUS || c == MINUS || c == MULTIPLY || c == DIVIDE || c == OPENBRACE || c == CLOSEBRACE;
    }

    /**
     * If op1 has a higher precedence than op2.
     * 
     * @param op1   the first operator
     * @param op2   the second operator
     * @return      true if op1 has a higher precendence.
     */
    private static boolean higherPrecedence(char op1, char op2) {
        switch (op1) {
            case PLUS:
            case MINUS:
                return op2 == OPENBRACE;

            case MULTIPLY:
            case DIVIDE:
                return op2 == PLUS || op2 == MINUS || op2 == OPENBRACE;

            case OPENBRACE:
                return true;

            case CLOSEBRACE:
                return false;

            default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("The operator op1: " + op1 +  " or operator op2: "  + op2 + " is illegal.");
        }
    }

    private static StringBuilder getOperators(Stack<String> operatorStack) {
        final StringBuilder operators = new StringBuilder();
        /* eg: a + (b * c), here a,b and +, (, were in their respective stacks, and current char was ) */
        while (!operatorStack.isEmpty() && operatorStack.peek().charAt(0) != OPENBRACE) {
            operators.append(operatorStack.pop());
        }
        /* pop of the remaining open brace. */
        if (!operatorStack.isEmpty() && operatorStack.peek().charAt(0) == OPENBRACE) {
            operatorStack.pop();
        }
        return operators;
    }

    /**
     * Converts a valid infix to postfix expression
     * It is the clients responsibility to provide with a valid infix expression, failing which yeilds invalid results.
     * 
     * @param infix    the infix expression
     * @return         the postfix expressions
     */
    public static String toPostfix(String infix) {
        final Stack<String> operatorStack = new Stack<String>();
        final Deque<String> operandStack = new ArrayDeque<String>();

        char c;

        for (int i = 0; i < infix.length(); i++) {
            c = infix.charAt(i);

            if (c == ' ')
                continue;

            /* we either have an operator or we have have an operand. */
            if (isOperator(c)) {
                /* we either have a operator with higher or lower precedence.*/

                /* eg: a + b * c, here * has higher precedence over +, where ab and + were in respective stacks &
                  current character was */
                if (operatorStack.isEmpty() || higherPrecedence(c, operatorStack.peek().charAt(0))) {
                    operatorStack.push(c + "");
                } else {
                    /* eg: a * b + c, here * has higher precendence over +, where a,b and * were in respective stacks &
                      current character was +  */

                    String op2 = operandStack.pop();
                    String op1 = operandStack.pop();

                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(op1);
                    sb.append(op2);
                    sb.append(getOperators(operatorStack));

                    operandStack.push(sb.toString());
                    if (c != CLOSEBRACE) {
                        operatorStack.push(c + "");
                    }
                }
            } else {
                /* current char is an operand. */
                operandStack.push(c + "");
            }
        }

        /* Output the remaining operators from the stack. */
        while (!operatorStack.empty()) {
            operandStack.push(operatorStack.pop());
        }

        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (!operandStack.isEmpty()) {
            sb.append(operandStack.removeLast());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        assertEquals("AB*CD/+", InfixToPostfix.toPostfix("A * B+C / D"));
        assertEquals("ABC+*D/", InfixToPostfix.toPostfix("A* (B+C) / D"));
        assertEquals("ABCD/+*", InfixToPostfix.toPostfix("A * (B + C / D)"));
        assertEquals("AB*C/",   InfixToPostfix.toPostfix("A*B/C"));
        assertEquals("AB+C-",   InfixToPostfix.toPostfix("A+B-C"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Method comments vs. naming**
When the method and parameters are well names, in 9 out of 10 cases, the comment above the method is redundant. For example, `higherPrecedence(char op1, char op2)` - if you call `op1` `firstOperator` and `op2` `secondOperator` the comment above the method simply says the same thing as the method signature. Twice.

**Be consistent and precise**
`higherPrecedence("+", "-") == false`, but `higherPrecendence("-", "+") == false` as well... this is a very surprising result, and might result in inconsistent results.
When you get to the `default` case you throw an Exception which states that either `op1` or `op2` are illegal, although you *know* that `op1` is the illegal one, since you don't even check if `op2` is an operator.

**Magic Constants**
I find that `"+"` is much more descriptive than `PLUS`. These kind of constants add unnecessary ambiguity to your code, as they force the reader to go and check their actual value.
If you do decide to use a constant, I would suggest a single constant `OPERATORS_BY_PRECEDENCE`, which will result in these methods:

```
private static final OPERATORS_BY_PRECEDENCE = "(+-/*)";

private static boolean isOperator(char c) {
    return OPERATORS_BY_PRECEDENCE.indexOf(c) != -1;
}

private static boolean higherPrecendence(char firstOperator, char secondOperator) {
    return OPERATORS_BY_PRECEDENCE.indexOf(firstOperator) < 
        OPERATORS_BY_PRECEDENCE.indexOf(secondOperator);
}
```

Comment: Although I agree naming has room for improvement, there is a issue with solution you proposed. This problem says 'if precedence is the same, then go from left to right' which means - a+b-c is should be ab+c- and not abc-+ although the would compute to be the same

Comment: In that case I would propose that the method will return three states - higher priority, lower priority, or same priority